# How to draw a round point in vulkan?

Tags: rendering, vulkan

I'm able to render a point in vulkan by specifying `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST` in the graphics pipeline. But the resulting point is a small square.

How can I draw a round point in Vulkan? Is there an equivalent to [`GL_SMOOTH_POINT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)?

Comment: Vulkan doesn't mention such an option in that part of the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/chap25.html#primsrast-points). I'm betting such functionality isn't intrinsic to a GPU and thus is emulated via a hidden geometry shader in OpenGL; thus you could easily implement a geometry shader to generate a circular mesh centered on a point.

Comment: Thanks van for your answer. Now it is very clear that we must draw round points by our self ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there is no such functionality built-into Vulkan.

But you can easily emulate this in your point list rendering fragment shader by discarding fragments outside of a given circular radius like this:

```c
const float radius = 0.25;
if (length(gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5)) > radius) {
    discard;
}
```